# When are two identical "bugs" questions not identical?

Tags: discussion, reopen

Regarding [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98318/why-is-it-suddenly-raining-dragons) (which I asked):

It was originally closed as a duplicate because it appeared identical to a known bug in the game that was supposedly fixed by an unofficial community patch.

When I first asked the question, I did *not* think it was a duplicate for two reasons:

1. The circumstances behind my observed buggy behavior were different from those described in the accepted answer of the duplicate question.
2. The suggested fix given in the accepted answer of the duplicate question does not, in fact, fix my problem.

When it was closed as a duplicate, though, I didn't press the issue, but a comment on the question prompted me to come here and ask. Exactly how close do two questions about buggy behavior have to be before they count as duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that they're different and had voted to reopen your question. I also agree on both of your reasons.

From a [comment of mine there](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98318/why-is-it-suddenly-raining-dragons#comment134317_98318), in reply [to this comment on why your question should be closed as a duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98318/why-is-it-suddenly-raining-dragons#comment134304_98318):

> ...I thought that the [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35540/where-did-this-dragon-skeleton-come-from) had a different scope and was asking about NPCs fighting/killing dragons while the player character is on a different zone, what happens to a dragon's soul if it is killed by an NPC, and if the player can still collect the soul of a dragon killed by an NPC, rather than a bug with dragon random encounters on fast traveling.

Comment: They aren't different at all. It is very much a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

When they are asking about different bugs. If you can demonstrate that the bugs are not identical then there is no reason for one of them to be/remain closed as a duplicate.