# No revisions link in this closed and reopened question

Tags: support, feature-request, closing, revision-history

This is about this question: [Why is it suddenly raining dragons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98318/why-is-it-suddenly-raining-dragons)

It was closed and then reopened. (Related Meta post about that: [When are two identical "bugs" questions not identical?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/when-are-two-identical-bugs-questions-not-identical))

However, there is [currently no revisions link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPxvV.png) in the question.

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? If it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), I would like to make a feature request to allow showing the revisions link on a closed and reopened question. It would be helpful to see the history behind the closing and reopening of a question.

Comment: You should take a look at this: [Revision history missing on closed and re-opened questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69652/)

Comment: Related Feature Request on Meta SE: [Show link to revision history when there are revisions but no edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168765/179041)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that audit-level messages like closures are also now shown in the Timeline. 
For the question in question this is here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/98318/timeline, but on any question the Timeline can be accessed by clicking this button:

[image: Timeline button]

The button is always available, regardless of whether there are any revisions (edits) of the post itself. Close and reopen logs show up like this in the timeline:

[image: Short post timeline with close and reopen logs]

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), mostly because anything that is not an edit shows up in the revision history but does not count as an actual revision. I'm not really sure.

In any case, you can view the revision history of any post by visiting the URL of the form

```
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/<post-ID>/revisions
```

So, the revision history for the question you are asking about can be viewed at

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/98318/revisions